# Python won't compare strings

Tags: python, string, sockets

I have a python script that is listening on a socket.
Code looks something like this:

```
def clientthread(conn):
        while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if data == 'quit':
```

I'm connected to the server using telnet. When I sent quit, the code after "if data == 'quit':" doesn't execute. What is wrong?

Comment: `conn.recv` returns a `bytes` object, not a string.

Comment: Also, you are probably typing a carriage return and/or line feed, which will also be sent, (up to 1024 characters).  Better print(repr(data)) to see what you are really receiving.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.X or 3.X?

Comment: I am using Python 2.X

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2.X, then, perhaps stripping the received data before comparing it would help:

```
def clientthread(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data.strip() == 'quit':
```

If you're using Python 3.X, then the return value of [socket.recv()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) is a bytes object representing the data received. So, you should convert it to a string before doing the comparison:

```
def clientthread(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data.decode('UTF-8').strip() == 'quit':
```

Let me know if none of the above helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it would work most of the time if you remove the line break.

**But:** If you want any sort of reliability you can't just take the output of the recv and compare it to a command. The OS might split the data in any way it want's into more or less parts. So you could get 'qu' and then 'it\n' separately. You really need to buffer the return of recv and use for example startswith to match the next command and remove the executed commands.

Also as Colonel Thirty Two said in the comment if you are useing python 3.x they are byte strings so you need to compare to a byte string as b"quit"

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it to a `str` through `data.decode("utf-8")`. Currently it is currently a `bytes` object.